# display datetimepicker directly in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I use code below to host DatetimePicker in Datagridview :

```
public class CalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public CalendarColumn() : base(new CalendarCell())
        {
        }

        public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
        {
            get
            {
                return base.CellTemplate;
            }
            set
            {
                // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
                if (value != null &&
                    !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
                }
                base.CellTemplate = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {

        public CalendarCell()
            : base()
        {
            // Use the short date format.
            this.Style.Format = "hh:mm tt";
            
        }

        public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
            initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
                dataGridViewCellStyle);
            CalendarEditingControl ctl =
                DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
            // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
            if (this.Value == null)
            {
                ctl.Value = Convert.ToDateTime( this.DefaultNewRowValue);
            }
            else
            {
                ctl.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Value);
            }
        }

        public override Type EditType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
                return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
            }
        }

        public override Type ValueType
        {
            get
            {
                // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.

                return typeof(DateTime);
            }
        }

        public override object DefaultNewRowValue
        {
            get
            {
                // Use the current date and time as the default value.
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool valueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;

        public CalendarEditingControl()
        {
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            this.CustomFormat = "hh:mm tt";
            this.ShowUpDown = true;
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue
        // property.
        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Value.ToLongTimeString();
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is String)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // This will throw an exception of the string is
                        // null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
                        this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // In the case of an exception, just use the
                        // default value so we're not left with a null
                        // value.
                        this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Implements the
        // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
            DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }

        // Implements the
        // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
            DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
            this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
            this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex
        // property.
        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return rowIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                rowIndex = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey
        // method.
        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
            Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
            switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Home:
                case Keys.End:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit
        // method.
        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
            // No preparation needs to be done.
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get
            {
                return dataGridView;
            }
            set
            {
                dataGridView = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                valueChanged = value;
            }
        }

        // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
        // .EditingPanelCursor property.
        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Cursor;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
        {
            // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
            // have changed.
            valueChanged = true;
            this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        }
    }
```

it work fine , but it show up when i click on cell for edit, what i need is display DatetimePicker directly for each cell as when display DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn or DataGridViewButtonColumn,
how to edit this code to display DatetimePicker directly not when mouse click , or any other way to do that?

Comment: Why does your cell class inherit from `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` rather than`DataGridViewCell`?

Comment: i use the code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: As mentioned in the example :The cells of this column display dates in ordinary text box cells, but when the user edits a cell, a DateTimePicker control appears. In order to avoid having to implement text box display functionality again, the CalendarCell class derives from the DataGridViewTextBoxCell class rather than inheriting the DataGridViewCell class directly.

Comment: See if the [following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/datagridview-custom-columns) would work for you.

Comment: thanks but same problem which i have to click on cell to display the datetimepicker,  what i need is display DatetimePicker directly for each cell as when display DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn or DataGridViewButtonColumn

Comment: You need to override the `CalendarCell.Paint` method to draw that yourself when the `CalendarEditingControl` is not showing.